# Change strcpy parameter in a linux binary elf file

Tags: c, binary, elf

I am facing following problem: I have a compiled c program. I need to change one parameter in the binary executable. I know how to do this in linux for normal variables, editing the hex code. My question is, is there a solution to modify the content of the strcpy parameter:

```
strcpy(outSig, "test.examples.out");
```

So I need to replace test.examples.out with another string (same lenght) in the elf binary. Is this possible?

Thanks for your help

Comment: can you provide some sample code to help illustrate what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

If you can identify the place in the binary where "test.examples.out" lives, you can replace it with a new string assuming the new string is *not* longer than the current string.

If the new string is the same length as the old string, just replace the relevant characters.  If it is shorter, pad the extra bytes with the value 0.  That way the string is still properly null terminated, and any string functions operating on it shouldn't read past the first null byte.

Be sure to use a proper hex editor so that all bytes are properly preserved and not reinterpreted as a text editor might do.

Comment: Is there no CRC/checksum on the executable?

Comment: Also, there may be problems with AV apps.

Comment: Beware that this string can be used in multiple places, only one of which you need to change.

Comment: Also, multiple independent uses of the same string literal are likely to share a reference to a single string literal in the executable, so may be worth pointing out that if some other random function also happens to use the literal `"test.examples.out"`, then this method is also likely to affect that usage, which may or may not be desired.

Comment: Yes, that would be the idea, but i don't know how i can identify the section where the string is. I cannot find it using hexdump and searching for the string (converted to hex).